# Views content show current state - workbench

Tags: views, workbench

I have a page that lists all the content and want to display the current state for each node.

But for now I can only see published content on the page. The view of mine is a content view.

Can we make some changes in the view to show current state of nodes as well?

Have tried the Workbench Current state filter as well but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Have you already installed workbench moderation module?

I have used this module and it gives you a Workbench page with the tabs for each state of the nodes. The user can see which nodes are in Draft state and which are in review state.

You can adjust the look and feel of the page using panels and make it the way you want to display the content of each state.

In the views, you can add exposed filters for any other specific field you want to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Filter criteria of the views, simply add a field **Workbench Moderation: State** which would show the present state of the content.

[image]

Hoping that this would be helpful.